# OpenVPN client connect to 2 servers and route between

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn, linux-networking, routes

We are building a VPN network where there is a lot of small vpn-servers connected to each other to form a big network

diagram is something like this

- S on the image is VPN Server
- C on the image is VPN Client

each client is connected to one server (which then gives it the ip address)

[image: Network Graph]

I know how to create a vpn-client to connect to a vpn-server, the problem that I have is I don't know how to connect VPN client to 2 different servers and route traffic between them, I was thinking I would just run 2 vpn clients (maybe it would be possible with only one and specific entry in config), each connecting to one server and somehow route traffic between them so clients connecting to 192.168.20.1 server would be able to reach client on 10.11.24.4 and vice-versa

so when you add a new node you would just add a client and a server, set the route between them and the netowrk would expand, of course this is just an experiment so I don't want to go fency with finding shortest paths, just static routes

IF anyone has any idea, I would love to hear it
Thanks for Anwsering and Best Regards

Comment: You might want to consider a mesh-based VPN like `tinc`.

Comment: yea, tinc looks great, but unfortunately we have to use openVPN for this, so.. if you have any idea how to do that with OpenVPN that would be great